# The button does not work until the page loads or the option is selected

Tags: javascript

I broke my head trying to fix my simple script. I can't understand why my button is not active sometimes. Sometimes it's inactive until the page loads, sometimes it's inactive until an option is selected for a couple of times.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('#inputState').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('#anchorSubmit').setAttribute('href', `${event.currentTarget.value}`);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected value="/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35439&quantity=1">250 Instagram Followers ($7) </option>
        <option value="/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=201&quantity=1">500 Items ($13)</option>
        <option value="/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=194&quantity=1">1,000 Items ($19)</option>
      </select>
      <a class="pp__btn" type="submit" id="anchorSubmit">
    Submit
  </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: No, the Submit button is inactive until you choose an option, that's the problem

Comment: Of course the submit button is inactive until you choose an option – the href attribute is only added by your change handler. An a element without href attribute doesn't do anything

Comment: How in this case I can make the button active? Much appreciate your help

Comment: If you are really trying to sell `250 Instagram Followers ($7)`, be aware this is against the Instagram TOS (I'm not sure if we are supposed to answer questions that violate some other sites TOS)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80495/policy-regarding-questions-related-to-unethical-or-shady-practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in most browsers, links won't look clickable (e.g. they won't be blue with an underline) unless they have an `href`.

Your `<a>` tag/'submit' link has no `href` in the HTML. Thus, when the page loads, the link is not clickable.

Your code says that when someone changes the `<select>` menu it should change the `href` of the 'submit' link. Thus, the link only becomes clickable when someone changes the `<select>` menu.

It sounds like you want the `href` to be set twice: first when the page loads (using the default `<option>`, which is the one with the `selected` attribute), then when the `<select>` changes.

Like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // Set the `href` when the page loads
    const defaultOption = document.querySelector('#inputState option[selected]')
    document.querySelector('#anchorSubmit').setAttribute('href', defaultOption.value)

    // Set the `href` when the `select` changes
    document.querySelector('#inputState').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        document.querySelector('#anchorSubmit').setAttribute('href', `${event.currentTarget.value}`);
    });
}
```

Here's how I would do it:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // Save these two elements to variables, so you can re-use them later
    // This way you don't have to run `querySelector` as many times, so you have better performance
    const inputMenu = document.querySelector('#inputState')
    const submitLink = document.querySelector('#anchorSubmit')

    // Create a function for getting whatever option is selected right now
    const updateHrefFromSelectedOption = function(){
        const selectedOption = inputMenu.querySelector('option[selected]')
        submitLink.setAttribute('href', selectedOption.value)
    }

    // Set the `href` when the page first loads
    updateHrefFromSelectedOption()
    // Set the `href` when the `select` changes
    inputMenu.addEventListener('change', updateHrefFromSelectedOption)
}
```

Comment: Could you, please, let me know how I can do that in my case? Much appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Of course the submit button is inactive until you choose an option – the href attribute is only added by your change handler. An a element without href attribute doesn't do anything. You can easily fix this by adding the href with the default value, like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('#inputState').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('#anchorSubmit').setAttribute('href', `${event.currentTarget.value}`);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected value="https://www.mrinsta.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35439&quantity=1">250 Instagram Followers ($7) </option>
        <option value="/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=201&quantity=1">500 Items ($13)</option>
        <option value="/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=194&quantity=1">1,000 Items ($19)</option>
      </select>
      <a class="pp__btn" type="submit" id="anchorSubmit" href="https://www.mrinsta.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35439&quantity=1">
    Submit
  </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that if you ever change the URL of the default `<option>`, or you change which `<option>` is default in the first place, you will also need to change the `href` attribute in your HTML. It would be better practice to use JavaScript to get the `href` of whatever `<option>` happens to be default.